# EXCEL VBA works with F5 - but will not run automatically when cell values are changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

The VBA formula works perfect with F5

Column E cells E3:E5 have Functions that calculate to a dollar amount ***or*** $0.00.

This is the formula pulling from  `=SUM('MEDENT Proposal - Creator'!B15*15)`

If the result is $0.00 the line is **hide** -- if it is greater than 0 it is **unhide**

```
Sub hidelines2()  
      If Range("E3").Value = 0 Then  
         Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True  
  ElseIf Range("E3").Value > 0 Then  
         Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = False  
  End If  
      If Range("E4").Value = 0 Then  
         Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True  
  ElseIf Range("E4").Value > 0 Then  
         Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False  
  End If  
      If Range("E5").Value = 0 Then  
         Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True  
  ElseIf Range("E5").Value > 0 Then  
         Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False  
  End If  
End Sub
```

**My Problem:** I cannot get this to **automatically run** when the cell values are changed.
*There have been a few suggestions, but none have worked.*

Answer (score 0):

You should add a call to your sub on the `Worksheet_Calculate` event of the sheet you wish to update.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Call hidelines2

End Sub
```

It is important you've put it in the right place, see the animation below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the exceptional effort.  
I do not want to bother you more with this - your time is valued. ( I will try to find a workaround )  
  
**I now get**
_method 'hidden' of object 'range' failed_ **then** 
_Automation error Exception occurred_

EXCEL window is then killed

Comment: @EdRegis sorry, does this not work for you, or is this not what you wanted?

Comment: I followed the instruction exactly, but it led to the above errors.

Comment: @EdRegis that's strange, I didn't edit your code, just added it to the calculate event. What version of excel?

Comment: 2016 - I can send you the entire spreadsheet if you are interested

Comment: @EdRegis I'm not at my laptop until Thursday now, but I can take a look then if it's not too urgent.

Comment: Thanks that is generous - but, I will not take up your time on this one.  :-)

Comment: FYI - call is no longer needed. As I've found out, `Worksheet_Calculate` doesn't fire on formula changes.

Comment: @Raystafarian that's strange, calculate seemed to function as I had expected for me (at least, in the GIF I made it was doing as I hoped). I also put call because it threw an error, which I now think was because I put empty parentheses after the sub name. What behavior does calculate display for you?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. No change events are triggered by a formula update, that I know of

Comment: @Raystafarian That's bizarre, any idea why it worked for me? That is the only event I was using in my post and it worked perfectly (only on formula change, if I manually updated the cell nothing happened). I'm incredibly confused now!

Comment: I have no idea - are you on 2016? All the documentation I could find noted that formula calculation doesn't trigger an event, but maybe it changed in 2016?

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes I am, although [this thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/425270-when-worksheet_calculate-generated.html) from 2009 sounds like people were getting the expected event triggering on a formula change response. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need this on a large scale, this will work -

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("E3") = 0 Then
        Range("E3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else: Range("e4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("E4") = 0 Then
        Range("E4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else: Range("e4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
     If Range("E5") = 0 Then
        Range("E5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else: Range("e5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

It's not like you'll see E3, E4 or E5 unless you change your selection somewhere on the sheet. This is not good for large scale though, at all.

[This was the best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11409569/1161309) solution I could find.